# SSH over WiFi suddenly stops on laptop

Tags: ssh

I have a laptop running Ubuntu server with Plex (Server runs on WiFi (2.4 GHz)). When sshing into the server it usually works but randomly (like after 40min) it says host down despite laptop still running and I have to reboot the server to use ssh again.

*Edit- I have noticed a pattern this usually happens when I disconnect from ssh by typing exit and after 10min minutes or more it says host down... etc the only solution I can do is to run htop or any other command to stop it from disconnecting.

```
onlysaikihere@hub: $ client_loop: ssh_packet_write_poll: Connection to 192.168.0.145 port 22: Host is down
sahishnukumar@Sahishnu-kumar ~ % ssh onlysaikihere0192.168.0.145
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.145 port 22: Host is down
sahishnukumar@Sahishnu-kumar ~ % ssh onlysaikihere@192.168.0.145
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.145 port 22: Host is down
sahishnukumar@Sahishnu-kumar ~ % ssh onlysaikihere0192.168.0.145
ATTA
AC
sahishnukumar@Sahishnu-kumar
~ % ssh onlysaikihere@192.168.0.145
```

using mosh gives following output

```
sahishnukumar@Sahishnu-kumar ~ % mosh onlysaikihere@192.168.0.145
/opt/homebrew/bin/mosh: Could not connect to 192.168.0.145, last tried 192.168.0.145: Host is down
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
/opt/homebrew/bin/mosh: Did not find remote IP address (is SSH ProxyCommand disabled?).
sahishnukumar@Sahishnu-kumar ~ %
```

plex server also stop working

**FORMATTED LAPTOP AND ISSUE FIXED**

Comment: Check the logs on the server. The problem is probably on the server. On the laptop, `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager` may supply more information.

Comment: Please copy/paste and format text instead of pictures of text. A picture (of text) can't be read on a text-only terminal, can't be copied from (edited, tried, and made to work), AND makes one take an action to even read your Question. Since we're all volunteers, some won't.

Comment: @waltinator updated it by adding text ,log is too long https://pastebin.com/Jd2ZUNnC

Comment: You can get more info with `ssh -v ...`. Also, for unstable connections you could use [mosh](https://mosh.org/) on top of ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting SSH up for regular pings:

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 60
```

Add this to the top of your `~/.ssh/config` and sessions should no longer drop. The default, larger interval does not prevent that from happening.

Comment: the file was empty for me , I added this to the top "Host * ServerAliveInterval 60"

Comment: @RetroXcalibur Did it work?

Comment: @mchid sorry I wasn't able to reply, I went to sleep , I left ssh on with yt-dlp downloading playlist and when I woke up ssh was up and connected so I guess this fixed it as I was connected to server for  8 hours

Comment: the problem started again.

Comment: Maybe your Wi-Fi was inactive long enough to skip some keep-alives, such as by being in sleep mode.